# Consequences of #P = FP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, complexity-classes, counting-complexity, ai.artificial-intel

Which would be the consequences of #P = FP?

I'm interested in both practical and theoretical consequences.

From a practical point of view, I'm particularly interested in consequences on Artificial Intelligence.

Pointers to papers or books are more than welcome.

Please do not say that #P = FP implies P = NP, I already know that. Also, please do not say *"there will be no practical consequences if the algorithm runs in time $\Omega(n^{\alpha})$, where $\alpha$ is the number of electrons in the Universe"*: permit me to assume that, if a deterministic polynomial time algorithm for a #P-complete problem exists, its running time will be "clement" ($O(n^2)$, for example).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are a few theoretical consequences of the equality FP=#P, although they have nothing to do with artificial intelligence.  The assumption FP=#P is equivalent to P=[PP](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo:P#pp), so let me use the latter notation.

If P=PP, then we have P=[BQP](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo:B#bqp): quantum polynomial-time computation can be simulated by classical, deterministic polynomial-time computation.  This is a direct consequence of BQP⊆PP [ADH97, FR98] (and of an earlier result BQP⊆P<sup>PP</sup> [BV97]).  On top of my knowledge, P=BQP is not known to follow from the assumption P=NP.  This situation is different from the case of randomized computation ([BPP](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo:B#bpp)): since BPP⊆NP<sup>NP</sup> [Lau83], the equality P=BPP follows from P=NP.

Another consequence of P=PP is that the Blum-Shub-Smale model of computation over the reals with rational constants is equvalent to Turing machines in a certain sense.  More precisely, P=PP implies P=BP(P<sub>ℝ</sub><sup>0</sup>); that is, if a language *L*⊆{0,1}<sup>*</sup> is decidable by a constant-free program over the reals in polynomial time, then *L* is decidable by a polynomial-time Turing machine.  (Here “BP” stands for “Boolean part” and has nothing to do with BPP.)  This follows from BP(P<sub>ℝ</sub><sup>0</sup>)⊆[CH](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo:C#ch) [ABKM09].  See the paper for definitions.  An important problem in BP(P<sub>ℝ</sub><sup>0</sup>) is the [square-root sum problem](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/complexity_of_square_root_sum) and friends (e.g. “Given an integer *k* and a finite set of integer-coordinate points on the plane, is there a spanning tree of total length at most *k*?”) [Tiw92].

Similarly to the second argument, the problem of [computing a specific bit in *x*<sup>*y*</sup> when positive integers *x* and *y* are given in binary](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/complexity-of-exponential-function) will be in P if P=PP.

References

[ABKM09] Eric Allender, Peter Bürgisser, Johan Kjeldgaard-Pedersen and Peter Bro Miltersen.  On the complexity of numerical analysis.  *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 38(5):1987–2006, Jan. 2009.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/070697926

[ADH97] Leonard M. Adleman, Jonathan DeMarrais and Ming-Deh A. Huang.  Quantum computability.  *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 26(5):1524–1540, Oct. 1997.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539795293639

[BV97] Ethan Bernstein and Umesh Vazirani.  Quantum complexity theory.  *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 26(5):1411–1473, Oct. 1997.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539796300921

[FR98] Lance Fortnow and John Rogers.  Complexity limitations on quantum computation.  *Journal of Computer and System Sciences*, 59(2):240–252, Oct. 1999.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcss.1999.1651

[Lau83] Clemens Lautemann.  BPP and the polynomial time hierarchy.  *Information Processing Letters*, 17(4):215–217, Nov. 1983.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(83)90044-3

[Tiw92] Prasoon Tiwari.  A problem that is easier to solve on the unit-cost algebraic RAM.  *Journal of Complexity*, 8(4):393–397, Dec. 1992.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0885-064X(92)90003-T

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, The last implication (P=NP imply P=BPP) is incorrect according to this [Complexity poster, LANDSCAPE OF COMPUTATIONAL COMPLEXITY, 
Faramawi and Regan](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/ComplexityPoster.pdf) The diagram shows that there are some problems in BPP which are not in NP. Could you please provide references?

Comment: You beat me to this! Actually, you are right about BQP vs NP. There seems to be reasonable evidence that BQP is not contained in PH (see for example http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4698), although I believe the Generalized Linial-Nisan Conjecture which is used in the second bit has since been shown to be incorrect.

Comment: @turkistany: If I'm not mistaken, P=NP implies P=BPP because BPP is contained in PH, and if P=NP then P=PH.

Comment: Incidentally: +1 for (FP=#P)⇔(P=PP), even setting aside the rest of the content of the answer.

Comment: @Niel de Beaudrap: Yes, that is why P=NP implies P=BPP.  @turkistany: I added a reference in the answer.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks for the comment.  Yes, BQP is not believed to be in PH, but I wonder how strongly it supports the intuitive claim “P=NP will not imply P=BQP.”  Inspired by your comment, I have posted a [related question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/a-decision-problem-which-is-not-known-to-be-in-ph-but-will-be-in-p-if-pnp).

Comment: @Joe: In light of the answers to the other question, I think that the best evidence of “P=NP does not imply P=BQP” without actually proving P=NP≠BQP would probably be an oracle separation result: “There exists an oracle A such that P^A=NP^A≠BQP^A.”  Of course, this is not easy at all because that result would imply BQP^A⊈PH^A, settling a big open question.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Can't you construct such an oracle from any oracle relative to which BQP is not contained in PH, simply by taking it together with PH to form a new oracle?

Comment: @Joe: You are right!  Thanks, I did not realize that at all.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: No problem. It's this kind of thing that makes the site useful. I very much liked you comment about the kind of oracle separation that would be good evidence.

Answer (score 15):

In [graphical models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model), many of the estimation problems are #P-complete, because they involve doing sum-product calculations a la the permanent over general graphs. If #P = FP, then graphical models suddenly get a whole lot easier, and we don't have to muck around with low-treewidth models anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Toda proved that any problem in the polynomial-time hierarchy can be reduced to #P function. Formally, he proved that $PH \subseteq P^{\#P}$. So if $\sharp P=FP$ then the $PH$ would collapse and consequently Tautologies would have short proofs.

Comment: i think it's a typo for polynomial.

Comment: Can someone clarify: is this not the same as saying "P=PH" (which would immediately follow from P=NP)?

Comment: @Niel: It's not the same, it is stronger.

Comment: @Walter: in what way? Is not $\text P^{\text{FP}} = \text P$? If so, then $\#\text P = \text{FP}$ would imply $\text{PH} \subseteq \text P^{\#\text P} = \text P^{\text{FP}} = \text P \subseteq \text{PH}$.

Comment: @Niel: Sorry, I read your first comment too quickly and I completely misunderstood your question. Of course what you said is right. What I meant in my comment was the very obvious fact that #P = FP is a stronger statement than P = NP.

Comment: @All: just to clarify --- my first comment above was asking the following question *"Is turkistany's answer equivalent to the statement that FP=#P implies P=PH?"* If I wanted to know whether FP=#P was equivalent to P=PH, I would have asked this in a comment on the original post, not on turkistany's answer.

Comment: @Niel: You're right. This is the same as saying P = PH, which follows from P = NP. Therefore the use of Toda's theorem was not necessary, since FP = #P already implies P = NP = PH.