# Does P = NP imply NP being a strict subset of PSPACE?

Tags: np-hardness, pspace

Does $\textbf{P} = \textbf {NP}$ imply that $\textbf{NP} \subsetneq \textbf{PSPACE}$? Or, for a slightly stronger result, does it imply that $\textbf{NL} = \textbf P$?

Comment: FWIW, the answer to original question was "yes" while the answer to the edited question is "no" (as far as we know; as explained by D.W.'s answer). They don't ask the same thing.

Comment: @HuckBennett D.W. explained that P=NP and reachability being NP-complete are iff, and I agree. If P=NP, reachability is trivially NP-complete.

Comment: No, he did not and what you said isn't right. Directed s-t connectivity is NL-complete, and P = NP does not (is not known to) imply that NL = NP. (I just wanted to clarify this in case anyone looks at previous versions of the question.)

Comment: @HuckBennett What I said is right. Reachability is in P, hence NP-completeness implies P=NP. P=NP implies that any problem in P is NP-complete.

Comment: Yes, I see, you're right about that. My point is about the difference between P = NP and NL = NP though (which affects the answer to your question).

Comment: @HuckBennett Elaborate, please. Are you saying that reachability being NP-complete does imply NP!=PSPACE?

Comment: Yes, then we would have $NP = NL \neq PSPACE$, where $NL \neq PSPACE$ holds for the reason mentioned in Mikhail Rudoy's comment below.

Comment: @HuckBennett I don't [think so](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/75942/22754). Or perhaps we're talking past each other.

Comment: Sorry, you're right again. The issue is that an NL-complete language being NP-complete doesn't imply that NL = NP since completeness is defined under different types of reductions for the two classes.

Comment: Yes, it does. This is a corollary to my proof of $\textbf{P}\ne\textbf{NP}$, which unfortunately does not fit into this comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  It is possible (as far as we know) that $\textbf{P} = \textbf{NP} = \textbf{PSPACE}$.

If $\textbf{P} = \textbf{NP}$, the [polynomial hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy) collapses, i.e., $\textbf{P} = \textbf{PH}$.  See also [Can one amplify P=NP beyond P=PH?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5463/5038) for an attempt to understand the limits of the implications of $\textbf{P} = \textbf{NP}$, and see [Why doesn't P=NP imply P=AP (i.e. P=PSPACE)?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5399/5038) for information about why it seems hard to derive the implication $\textbf{P} = \textbf{PSPACE}$.

Comment: Note that also, $P = PSPACE$ implies that $NL \ne P$ since $NL \ne PSPACE$ ($NL \subseteq SPACE((\log n)^2) \subsetneq PSPACE$ by Savitch's theorem and the space hierarchy theorem).