# Unique factorization representation and complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, nt.number-theory

Suppose that $N = p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} ... p_k^{a_k}$ with $p_i$ prime and $a_i \geq 1$.

Given a representation of the factorization of $N$ and an integer $m$ (using alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1,,\}$):

**Input:** $\quad m,p_1, a_1, ..., p_k, a_k$

What is the time and space complexity of calculating the $m$-th bit of the binary representation of $N$?

I asked a [similar question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156093/comparing-two-numbers-given-their-factorization) a few weeks ago, but didn't get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The simpler question about the $i$th bit of $a^b$: [Complexity of exponential function](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1811/).

Comment: @Kaveh I think the question you mention is a special case of this one only when $a$ is prime. Not sure if this makes any difference.